# "HEAD not found below refs/heads" after I push commit with CR/CRLF changes

Tags: git

I have local repository, and a remote bare repository. I've made changes to my local files, and other guy has made changes too, but he just sent me files. I've copy-pasted them in my local tree and committed. On commit I've got messages on files that I have copy-pasted

> LF will be replaced by CRLF

I've just committed all the files and pushed them to remote bare repository. And when on remote I run

```
git branch
```

I get the next error message

```
HEAD not found below refs/heads!
```

Now it seems to me that this is because of these files with CR instead of CRLF.

Any suggestions? Will appreciate any help on how to handle such situations/fix my repo.

Comment: Please show the output of `git symbolic-ref HEAD` on the remote.

Comment: I've run this one and figured out what's wrong, thanks )
The problem was that I've previously run something like
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/headss/my_branch

Comment: OK, I've added an answer saying as much for future reference in case it helps people searching for the error message which you got.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like the `HEAD` on your remote is pointing to an invalid branch. You can view what it's pointing to with:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD
```

and fix it to point at a valid branch with:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/branch-that-exists
```

Answer (score 3):

> I get the next error message
>
> > HEAD not found below **refs/heads**!

It means that 'HEAD' points outside of '**refs/heads**'.
For example, in my case it was pointing into '**refs/remotes**'

> git symbolic-ref HEAD
>
> > **refs/remotes**/coreclr/master

I had to edit 'HEAD' to fix the issue:

> git symbolic-ref HEAD
>
> > **refs/heads**/master