# GIT: Corrupt MERGE_HEAD file when merging with master

Tags: github, git-commit

When i tried to merge with `master` branch from **GitHub**, i got lots of conflict. I have fixed all of them and tried to commit. But i got following message:

```
fatal: Corrupt MERGE_HEAD file (0da861af91a7df624577f1aa4ee0716b3dffa4af)
```

When i tried by GUI mode i got `HEAD file not exist` type message. I have added the screenshot as following:

[image]

Now im confused how to solve it! I have searched in google and stackoverflow. But i dont get any solution. Please help me.

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551574/head-not-found-below-refs-heads-after-i-push-commit-with-cr-crlf-changes

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what causes this problem, but what fixed it for me was to stash everything with `git stash`, and then get it all back via `git stash pop`, after which I could once again commit the merged changes (I'm guessing the stash / pop thing resets HEAD and the merge state, replacing the file that got corrupted).

The only downside is that you'll lose the default commit message with the list of merge conflicts, so might be worth cutting and pasting this somewhere first if you do want to use it.

Comment: If the idea is to simply reset the merge state, an alternative would be to delete any `.git/MERGE_*` files.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. I had to call `git add .` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

When in a merge conflict situation, the first step is to resolve on conflicts, then add the files to the staging area. Generally these steps are best performed through the command line.

If all files are edited and resolved, use the command line and at the root of the project run:

`git add .`

Next, verify all files were staged by checking the status of the repository:

`git status`

Complete the merge by making the commit:

`git commit -m'<your message>'`

Comment: I have the same problem. This is not merge conflict, this is something more serious. Run into this problem when I first pull a git subtree from upstream, then rebase the remote.

Answer (score 0):

May be something occurred when you pulling/pushing. I solve this by reset HEAD. git reset HEAD^1